# Where notification.number in Android ICS

Tags: android, notifications, numbers, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

In Android ISC (4.0) not show number of noftification specified as notification.number. 
In earlier versions this work.
How to set notification to the number in ICS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works on ICS, but it only shows up if the user views the notification in the notification drawer, not in the status bar. Also, I find the number to be rather small. And, it does not work if you provide a custom `RemoteViews` for the notification drawer entry.

See [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21477) for more.

Comment: I really find this is a pity. I liked the ability to see the pending message count overlaid over the status icon.